# Why this menu doesn't work in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, menu

Why this second level doesn't open?

http://www.soauto.pt/soauto/quemsomos.htm

In IE works fine but in Chrome and Safari not open.

Comment: In Firefox it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 1):

First of all... very diffucult to find out what you are asking for.  Next time, it wouldn't hurt to add a little code and more information - it works in IE, but not chrome... what else?

Where I think the issue might lie is with this line :

```
 document.getElementById(strMenu).style.visibility = 'visible';
```

I think this might solve the issue as this is what worked for me.

```
document.getElementById("addEvent").style.display = "block";
```

And then have the `style.display` change back to `"none"` when you want it to hide.

As of right now, the `#mainmenu li ul` has the attribute `display:none` and I couldn't find anything that would change that.  Again, I didn't take the time to look through all your files.  This is why it's important to leave code in your question.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I can't see where this line your are talking :(

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it would be in this file : `MainMenu.js` and then in `function MostrarMenu(strMenu)`.  You'll have to go from there.

Comment: Because i am new here, i can add a full information with code and pictures